# removing dynamicaly added element in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Im adding an element to my page using:

```
var di = document.createElement("div");
di.id='container';
document.body.appendChild(di)
```

now when im trying to remove the element using internet explorer 8 and jQuery like :

```
jQuery(di).remove();
```

im getting inconsistent behavior .. meaning it is working on all browsers except for internet explorer 8 (probably the same on ie7 but i dont care anymore :-) )

any thoughts ?

thanks

Comment: Is this still the case when you call `$('#container').remove();`?

Comment: What about `di.parentNode.removeChild( di );`? If it doesn't work, your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if the element was added with jQuery :

```
var di = jQuery("<div/>").attr('id','container').appendTo('body');
```

Then :

```
di.remove();
```

Comment: Very odd. Can you hard-code a div in your HTML and append the dynamically created div to that instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the code is not working in IE8? It looks like that you have to refresh the content of the Developer Tools to see the added/removed div.

I just did a test with the following code and it is working in FF and in IE8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="main" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add() {
            var di = document.createElement("div");
            di.id='container';
            di.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Testing'));
            document.body.appendChild(di)
        }
        function remove() {
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('container'));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="add();">Add</button>
    <button onclick="remove();">Remove</button>
</body>
</html>
```